# how to find document by the populate field in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

My Product Schema Look like this.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
   {
       name: { type: String, required: true },

       game: {
           type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
           ref: 'Game',
           required: true,
       },
       category: {
           type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
           ref: 'Category',
           required: true,
       },
       slug: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
       image: { type: String, required: true },
       price: { type: Number, required: true },
       nominal: { type: Number, required: true },
       description: { type: String, required: true },
   },
   {
       timestamps: true,
   }
);

const Product =
   mongoose.models.Product || mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
export default Product;
```

My schema game

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const gameSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            require: [true, 'Type cant be empty'],
        },
        status: {
            type: String,
            enum: ['Y', 'N'],
            default: 'Y',
        },
        thumbnail: {
            type: String,
            require: [true, 'Type cant be empty'],
        },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);
const Game = mongoose.models.Game || mongoose.model('Game', gameSchema);
export default Game;
```

I want to find a product by the game status is 'Y'

I try to do like this

```
const getHandler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
        await db.connect();
        const options = { status: { $regex: 'Y', $options: 'i' } };
        const products = await Product.find({}).populate({
            path: 'game',
            select: 'status',
            match: options,
        });

        res.send(products);
        await db.disconnect();
    };
```

but is not work
is not filtering.
the output is still the same but for the products with a game  status is 'N' it shows null

I heard that we could use aggregation with $lookup but I still don't know how to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
let data = await Product.aggregate([
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "games", //Your model name which is in mongoose DB
    localField: "game", //field name of product which contains game id
    foreignField: "_id", // _id of game
    pipeline: [
      {
        $match: {
          status: "Y",
        },
      },
    ],
    as: "game", //name of result
  },
 },
 { $unwind: "$game" },// this will make your array to object and also it will remove all null entry.
]);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: the result is still the same it shows the product with game status 'N'. but game is Null like this. 
```{
_id: "638792c90f0931e2cd43c287",
name: "Test",
game: null,
}
```

Comment: That should not happen, let me execute some code and provide you another solution.

Comment: Please go thorough my answer, i have changed my answer with aggregate query.

Comment: thank you for helping me a lot. unfortunately, this still not working it gives me empty arrays. after searching for $lookup there is nothing wrong with the code. I don't know why, here if u want to see inside my DB and the code I'm using [Product db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrXLD.png) 
[Game db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9fPV.png)
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx60j.png)
is there something wrong with my db?

Comment: add your full output link also.

Comment: its working now with this code [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDV4m.png)

Comment: Then your model name in database must be games correct ?

Comment: Yes, i registered my model as Game and inside my  db  the name is games

Comment: while aggregate in the lookup you must use the model name in from field.

Comment: can you verify the answer since it is correct one now.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry i forgot

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

```
   const products = await Product.find({}).populate({
        path: 'game',
        model:'Game',
        match: {'status':'Y'}
        select: 'status'
    });
```

Comment: the result still same
```{
_id: "638792c90f0931e2cd43c287",
name: "Test",
game: null,
category: "63878f3ff1201de8b8037849",
}
```